# Queues in iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uitableview

I am trying to create queues in `Objective C` for iOS project. I want the Activity Monitor to run on th e main thread and continue doing that until I have all the data for my `UITableView`. Here is my code

```
[super viewDidLoad];
    // create the activity indicator in the main queue
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *ac = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                                   initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [ac startAnimating];

    });


    MyQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.gcd", NULL);
    dispatch_async(MyQueue, ^{

                                self.client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:@"https://outnight-mobile.azure-mobile.net/" applicationKey:@"okYeRGfBagYrsbkaqWIRObeDtktjkF10"];
                                self.table = [self.client tableWithName:@"notifications"];
                                self.rowitems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                                MSQuery *query = [self.table query];
                                query.fetchLimit = 3;
                                [query readWithCompletion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error)
                                        {
                                                //add the items to our local cop
                                                self.rowitems = [items mutableCopy];
                                                //[self.TableView reloadData];
                                        }];


    });
```

So you can see I have created a main thread for the `UIActivityIndiactor` and then a second thread for my sql work. 
The Indicitor does not work and it goes straight to the `UITableView` and it does not even go to myQueue for the dispatch. 
Does this mean that my `UIActivityIndicitor` is not working, so it doesn't do anything ? 
I am trying to use `GCD` so that I can get all my data prepared before running `[tableview reload data]`. Anyone with any advice ?

thanks

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not 'create the main thread'. `viewDidLoad` is already called on the main thread so you are just queuing a block to be executed later on the main thread. That block creates an instance of `UIActivityIndicatorView` which is then destroyed (because you don't add it as a subview or store a reference to it).

Remove that block, add it as a subview and store a reference to it in an @property.

Your second block of code queues code to be run on a background thread (though it doesn't create that thread directly). This block should additionally be:

1. Calling back to the main thread, and doing:
2. Removing the `UIActivityIndicatorView` from display
3. Reloading the table view

**BUT:**

You're using `MSQuery`. IIRC this needs to be run from the main thread. It runs all of the networking on a background thread automatically and calls back (completion block) to the main thread.

So, you should probably be removing your other use of GCD and just modifying the activity indicator and reloading the table view.

Comment: yep I understand that the second block does need to do these things thanks, but how do you add the UIActivtity as a subview ?

Comment: Set it's position and then `[self.view addSubview:ac];`

Comment: @user3229170 Remember, for the most part, UIKit classes should be used only from an application’s main thread. Including UIActivityIndicatorView and UITableView.

Comment: I have done that and yes an activity monitor comes up, but so does the UITableView , so it doesn't block everything. I need it to block all other activity until the data is retrieved, then I will RELOAD the TABLEVIEW if you get what i mean.

Comment: You do not want to block. Hide the table view and unhide it when you remove the activity indicator. If `self.view` is the table view then you will need to consider what you're doing (maybe MBProgressHud).

Comment: I cannot see the tableview to hide it. [self.uitableview.HIDE] does not show. IS that because it is in self.view ?

Comment: right got it. so the order is : 1, hide tableview 2, run activity monitor, 3, run the SQL query block do processing etc, 3 reload the tableview, 4 unhide the tableview ? does this seem right ?

Comment: Order is right. Code more like `self.tableView.hidden = YES;`